Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 (Need Sample Database of Magento 1)
Need Sample Database of Magento 1 to practice the migration to Magento 2. Can anyone help me to get only the M1 database ?

I found the answer. i got sql file from https://github.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/blob/master/compressed-no-mp3-magento-sample-data-1.9.2.4.tbz

please write it as your answer and mark it as accepted to indicate that the issue has been resolved.

You can found the Magento 1 sample database from here.

https://github.com/Vinai/compressed-magento-sample-data/tree/master


This will help you to download Magento 1 database..
https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/a16b66f722f0786d6730
